# How to show custom options on swipe table cell in a simple way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I am working on a app which includes table cells. I want that when i swipe table cell it shows two options, first about that cell value and another for delete that value. How can i show that in a way that the cell value shows in half of cell and the options show in half of cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an out of the box solution, called [HHPanningTableViewCell](https://github.com/gloubibou/HHPanningTableViewCell). It does exactly what you need!

> HHPanningTableViewCell is a UITableViewCell implementing "swipe to reveal" a drawer view. Such a view typically holds action buttons applying to the current row.

Comment: Download the example project. It compiles and runs fine (tested on 6.1).

Comment: @AttilaH do you have any idea on second point in Q --> How can i show that in a way that the cell value shows in half of cell and the options show in half of cell.

Comment: You have to review setDrawerRevealed: in HHPanningTableViewCell.m. This method is responsible for the panning animation. Then modify it until it fit your needs!

Answer (score 1):

This library, SWTableViewCell, should help you:
https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

> An easy-to-use UITableViewCell subclass that implements a swipeable content view which exposes utility buttons (similar to iOS 7 Mail Application)

Comment: Could you add an example that uses SWTableViewCell to design a custom cell

Comment: Don't have an example I can share @Somu. Do you have code you're struggling with? I can take a look and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom cell and override Apple's behavior which is swipe left to delete and then show your options. You can add gesture recognizer to the cell and on swipe to left animate the cell content view and animate in your option view or however you like it to be. I can write up an example code if you need.